# nginx rewrite for blog category/slug to new URL?

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting, blogs

I've been trying to figure out how to rewrite a URL that contains a category and post slug to just use a date (year, month) with a slug in nginx, but can't figure it out.  I've seen several posts, but they are all converting yearly/monthly/daily/slug URLs to just slug.  For example, I am trying to convert:

```
http://example.org/category1/post-slug-a/ -> http://example.org/2014/01/post-slug-a/
```

Is there a way to do this, and if so can someone help me out here?

Thanks!
Drew

Comment: How do you know which year and month to use?

Comment: No idea. That's why I'm asking. I didn't think there's a way, but wanted someone to tell me that I was out of my mind.

Comment: If you are using wordpress or other cms that supports it (via settings), then is possible. Otherwise, you are out of luck.

Comment: Thought so. I not using Wordpress. Thanks